# google places api android returns java..lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to implement the Google Places API, but it keeps sending a java.lang.nullpointerexception.  I got the code off this site: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

From what I can gather I send the URL to some Google Server and get a response.  that response is in a JSON format and then it is parsed as my specific "Locations" object.  I think something happens during this parsing phase.  In the site they use some intermediary object PlacesList and I think that's where things go wrong because I don't understand it.

PlacesList:

```
        public class PlacesList implements Serializable {

    @Key
    public String status;

    @Key
    public List<Locations> results;
```

}

Google search:

```
       public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius)
        throws Exception {

    this._latitude = latitude;
    this._longitude = longitude;
    this._radius = radius;

    try {

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
        request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");


       PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
        Log.i("placelist.class", list.toString());
        // Check log cat for places response status
       // Log.i("Places Status", "" + list.status);

        return list;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}
```

in Main from MainActivity
System.err(6447):atcom.example.mapmapagain.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86) ==

```
              try {
        PlacesList places = ps.search(curr_lat, curr_longitude, 100.0);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
              04-26 19:10:52.839: W/System.err(4156): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
              04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
              04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
              04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
              04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
              04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
              04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
              04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
              04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
              04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
              04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
              04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):   at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
             04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
             04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
             04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
             04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
             04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
             04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:88)
             04-26 19:10:52.899: W/System.err(4156):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:814)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at com.example.mapmapagain.PlaceSearch.search(PlaceSearch.java:64)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at com.example.mapmapagain.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
             04-26 19:10:52.909: W/System.err(4156):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you working on emulator?

Comment: please post the exact stacktrace and everything else

Comment: can you map your pasted code with line numbers? like is Activity.java:5104 == "PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);" ?

Comment: I meant MainActivity:86 sorry :)

Comment: I actually only posted the part of the stacktrace with the error because everything else is just various Logs I made to myself from other methods.  And I am using a device not an emulator.

Comment: Also just added where MainActivity:86 error is located in code

Comment: It looks like `ps` is null.  Where was that supposed to have been assigned?

Comment: Yeah u were right.  It still doesn't return anything after initiating ps = new PlaceSearch() though.  I'm putting up a new stack trace now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing networking on the main UI thread which is now forbidden by the Android framework, as indicated by your `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception.

This is forbidden because imagine that your server is unreachable or that your user has a very slow internet connection. When the program starts that `search` function of yours, the UI will be completely frozen until it returns because the UI thread will be busy trying to contact that server.

Put your search function in an `AsyncTask`, or wrap it in a `Runnable`, so that it gets executed in its own thread. Have a look at this question for a good example [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That makes a lot of sense. I didn't realize why the AsyncTask was necassary before.

Comment: And it will be well worth you learning it! Pls mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem thanks